# Number of Iterations (Gradient Descent)

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, gradient-descent

I am learning about the **Gradient Descent Algorithm** and I implemented one such**(in python)** over the **Boston Housing data set(in sklearn)**. I have implemented a cost function as well which takes in all the coefficients, the intercept and the training data and returns the cost for those coefficients and intercept. I ran the algorithm over the Boston data set for **1500 iterations** and **learning_rate = 0.000003202**, and It converged successfully, giving the **least cost as 61.840725406571245**, but when I trained the sklearn's LinearRegression() algorithm over the same training data, and found the cost using .coef_ and .intercept_. It gave the **least cost as 19.958219814238042**. *So My question is How can one say the a certain number of iterations, will give me the least/optimal cost? Like say I run the algorithm for n times, and obtain a particular cost, then How will I know that this cost is good enough or do I need to reduce it further?*

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation sets in training. They will be a better indicator for the testing phase of your model performance than only the training error. Also, your `learning_rate` is quite small, which can cause the model to converge in large number of iterations. You can play with those parameters to see how it effects your training.

Comment: I tried increasing the learning rate, but on increasing, it failed to converge, and an overshoot occurred.

Comment: I have initialized all the coefficients and the intercept with 0. Should I play around that also? @Koralp Catalsakal

Comment: Generally, yes. Initialization, learning rate, use of intercept are different parameters that can effect the training. It is up to you to find the parameters that give better results for your task. For `Gradient Descent` it is not possible to just define the optimal parameters, but you have to search for them.

Comment: So, Is playing around, all these parameters **(num_iterations, learning_rate, batch_size, initialization of the coefficients, intercept)** the only thing what we can do or do we have some rough rule or some rough estimate to determine all these? @Koralp Catalsakal

Comment: There are usually some common practices for values of the parameters, but not really a definite rule.